# Android Studio - build.gradle, create one task to be executed from all modules

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have a lot of modules and `build.gradle` for all my modules. Now, I want to create one task (static analyser) that can be executed by all modules.

Example: I have 3 modules, A, B and C
I want to run this one task for all my modules one by one (reporting) by entering command like this in the terminal.

> ./gradlew moduleA:task -> then will generate report to module A
>   directory
>
> ./gradlew moduleB: task -> same as B

I don't want to create 3 same tasks and put inside each module's `build.gradle`.
Is there a way to do this?
Thank you.